# Docker react app Compilation error while running a Container locallly

Tags: reactjs, docker

when i created a docker file for my react app and expose it to port 3000 , the image got created succesfully and container also started , but while accesing the URl , its shows the error "Failed to Compile"

**My Docker file is**

```bash
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:12.18.1
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "/app"]
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

and my /dockerignore file is -

```
dockerfile
.dockerignore
.gitignore
```

The Error that we get after running the container -

```
./src/pages/VSeditor/listing/style.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/pages/VSeditor/listing/style.scss) SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: ../../../../../common-assets/css/variables.
        on line 1 of src/pages/VSeditor/listing/style.scss
>> @import "../../../../../common-assets/css/variables";
```

Can someone help me understand what is the error and how i can resolve it .

Comment: You probably need to exclude `node_modules` in your `.dockerignore` file too; otherwise your possibly-incorrect host `node_modules` tree will overwrite the `RUN npm install` tree in the last `COPY` line.  That may or may not be this problem.  Do you recognize the referenced `common-assets` directory; Is it part of this source tree or is it stored somewhere else?

Comment: Have tried adding node_modules in .dockerignore , but that doesnt works , regarding common-assets , its not present in the directory where i have written Dockerfile , can you suggest me ways to add common-assets while writing a docker file or while running a container.